# Access Firebase database specifics child item

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I have two children in a Firebase database like 1) Semester I Notes and 2) Semester II Notes.

I have successfully uploaded data into these children, but when I retrieve these items, it just returns the first child's data. Code for Firebase helper here - `name` is the variable of our Semester I Notes or Semester II Notes

```
public class FireBaseHelper {
    DatabaseReference db;
    boolean saved;
    String name;
    Query myref;
    ArrayList<Semester> semesters = new ArrayList<>();

    public FireBaseHelper(DatabaseReference db, String n) {
        this.db = db;
        myref=db.orderByChild("model").equalTo(n);
        name = n;
    }

    public boolean save(Semester s) {
        if (s == null) {
            saved = false;
        } else {
            try {
                db.child(name).push().setValue(s);
                myref=db.orderByChild("model").equalTo(name);
            } catch (DatabaseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                saved = false;
            }
            saved = true;
        }

        return saved;
    }

    public void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i("Getchildcount", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
        semesters.clear();

        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Semester semester = ds.getValue(Semester.class);
            semesters.add(semester);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Semester> retrieve() {
        myref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        return semesters;
    }
}
```

I call the `retrieve` method like this

```
Firebase helper = new FireBaseHelper(db, NameOfDb);
NotesAdapter adapter = new NotesAdapter(this, helper.retrieve());
//this is the list variable noteItem and I set adapter on it
notesItem.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[Model Image of Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUeit.png)

Comment: Please show us your code so far for *fetching* the desired nodes...

Comment: Check edited post

Comment: You're loading data from `myref=db.orderByChild("model").equalTo(n)`. There is no property `model`, so the query matches nothing.

Comment: how can i do this kindly help me

Comment: i want to upload  semester 1 notes in listview when i click on semester 1 button and when i click on second button then semester 2 notes upload on listview kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DatabaseReference childItem = mDatabase.child("child_item_name");`

[Firebase Realtime database Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)